# Ansible: How to categorize files by permissions?

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-facts

Im trying to categorize the files based on their permissions
and I have a problem with the JSON query.

The output I like to categorize

**Example**

```
user@test.example.com:~$ stat -c '%a %n' $(pwd)/*
644 /home/user/go
755 /home/user/sshified
644 /home/user/test.yaml
```

or

```
user@test.example.com:~$ find / -perm -4000 -type f -exec stat -c '%a %n' {} 2>/dev/null \;
4755 /usr/bin/mtr
4755 /bin/su
4777 /bin/app1
```

The query which doesn't give any output back.

**Ansible Code**

```yaml
   - name: Find binaries with suid bit set 
     shell: 
       cmd: stat -c '%a %n' folder/* 
     register: files-with-write
     failed_when: files-with-write.rc != 1 and files-with-write.rc != 0
     changed_when: false

   - set_fact:
     writeable_files: "{{files-with-write| to_json | from_json |json_query(\"[?ends_with(mode, '7') == `true`].{gr_name: gr_name, mode: mode, path: path }\") }}"

   - debug:
     msg:
     - "files: {{writeable_files}}
```

Comment: Instead of posting an image of code or output consider using the same format as your Ansible code, this is a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) module and see what attributes are available in the registered results. For example, given the files

```yaml
shell> stat -c '%a %n' test-476/*
644 test-476/go
755 test-476/sshified
664 test-476/test.yaml
```

the debug below lists the registered attributes of the files

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: test-476
        recurse: true
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.files.0.keys()|list|to_yaml
```

gives

```yaml
  result.files.0.keys()|list|to_yaml: |-
    [path, mode, isdir, ischr, isblk, isreg, isfifo, islnk, issock, uid, gid, size, inode,
     dev, nlink, atime, mtime, ctime, gr_name, pw_name, wusr, rusr, xusr, wgrp, rgrp,
     xgrp, woth, roth, xoth, isuid, isgid]
```

For example, use the attribute *wgrp* to select group-writable files

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        group_writeable_files: "{{ result.files|selectattr('wgrp') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ group_writeable_files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - test-476/test.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find files that are writeable, this can be much easier done on bash level:

```
   - name: Find writable by others
     command: find folder/ -perm /o+w 
     register: writable_others

   - name: Find writable by others or group
     command: find folder/ -perm /o+w,g+w 
     register: writable_others_group
```

Comment: actually i want to do this 
'''find / -xdev \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f ! -path '/proc/*' -exec ls -l {} \; 2>/dev/null '''   and with json query to categorize them which are writeable or with execute rights